# What happens when a Federal holiday falls on a weekend?

Tags: united-states, public-holidays

I thought the rules for holidays on a weekend would be similar to what's commonly observed in the private sector - take the weekday closest to the actual date.  But when I went to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_holidays_in_the_United_States#List_of_federal_holidays) to confirm, I found this:

> New Year's Day, Juneteenth, Independence Day, Veterans Day, and Christmas Day are observed on the same calendar date each year, irrespective of the day of the week.

Implying that if the holiday fell on a weekend it was business as usual for the weekdays on either side.  But that flies in the face of actual experience, for example 2023-01-01 fell on a Sunday but Monday 2023-01-02 was the observed holiday when everything was closed.  So is the information on Wikipedia incorrect or just poorly worded?

I also tried to find an authoritative list of observed holidays on a government site, but failed.  All the lists I found were compiled by private web sites.  I'd rather know the actual rules anyway.

Comment: [Please note that most Federal employees work on a Monday through Friday schedule. For these employees, when a holiday falls on a nonworkday -- Saturday or Sunday -- the holiday usually is observed on Monday (if the holiday falls on Sunday) or Friday (if the holiday falls on Saturday).](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/federal-holidays/) the shift to a non weekend day is only for Federal employees and it seems to be just a convention/tradition.

Comment: There is even a real law about it https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/5/6103 section b.

Comment: @Trilarion you might consider posting an actual answer based on that link, very helpful.

Comment: Wow. And in the rest of the world, if a holiday falls on a week-end, then it falls on a week-end. It's not magically moved to friday or monday.

Comment: @Stef I think you are mistaking having a day off work with e.g. having a particular meal

Comment: @Caleth What? I don't think this question was about having meals...

Comment: @Stef At least in the UK, days off for holidays with set dates fall on the Friday / Monday adjacent, so it's not "the rest of the world". Iirc most of Europe follows that scheme too. "Observing Christmas Day" might mean both "having a day off" and "having a big family gathering / meal"

Comment: @Caleth I see. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 4):

If a holiday falls on a weekend it is officially observed on the closest weekday for the purposes of the day off. If if falls on a Saturday that means it would happen on the Friday before and if it falls on Sunday the Monday after.

It should be noted that is what the government does and how a private company does it might be different. For example if new years day falls on a Saturday some places don't give the day off on the Friday but have it on Monday so both days are in the same year.

An easy way to check is to look at the schedules of government offices, banks and other places that close on holidays and see what day the are closed in cases like that.

[Fact Sheet: Federal Holidays - Work Schedules and Pay](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/pay-administration/fact-sheets/holidays-work-schedules-and-pay/)

> If January 20th falls on a Sunday, the next succeeding day (i.e., Monday, January 21st) is designated as the public observance of the inauguration of the President and thus becomes the legal holiday of Inauguration Day.

> "In Lieu of" Holidays
> All full-time employees, including those on flexible or compressed work schedules, are entitled to an "in lieu of" holiday when a holiday falls on the employee's nonworkday. Part-time employees are not entitled to an "in lieu of" holiday. If an agency's office or facility is closed due to an "in lieu of" holiday for full-time employees, the agency may grant paid excused absence to part-time employees who are otherwise scheduled to work on that day. (See 63 Comp. Gen. 306 (1984).)

Comment: Another way to check is to find the lists of federal or state or local holidays. Those are typically posted online a year in advance or more.

Comment: Similarly, if January 20th following the Election of the President falls on a Weekend, the President is legally sworn in at 1200 as required by law, but the actual swearing in ceremony is held the following Monday (since you cannot have it prior to the 1200 on the 20th of Jan.).   It's considered a Federal Holiday for those Federal workers who work within D.C. proper, mostly because the nightmare traffic the event causes.

Comment: AFAIK private companies don't have to provide *any* days off by default, holiday or not.

Comment: @JonathanReez You are correct but a lot of them do provide a set of Federal holidays off and when those days fall on a weekend they need to be adjusted. And I know of a few that move new years day to a Monday if it falls on a Saturday which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: @JoeW Moving the day off for New Years Day from Saturday to Friday is a bit of an accounting pain. It means there are N+1 holidays in the previous year and N-1 in the following, where N is the nominal number of holidays per year. But that's how the US federal government works.

Comment: @DavidHammen To be honest you know when this is going to happen before hand so it isn't hard to plan for having an extra holiday in one year and one less in the next year. Granted I don't have a lot of history at different companies but I find it more common to be celebrated on Friday then waiting till the new year.

Comment: I know someone who worked at a company that *would not* move holidays if they fell on a weekend. And you were doubly screwed for Christmas and New Year’s, and since they were in “different years” they didn’t care that it was basically missing 2 holidays in the span of a week. Private companies have a lot of leeway here …

Comment: @fyrepenguin good to see that Mr. Scrooge is alive and well.

Answer (score 2):

There are 11 Federal Holidays:

New Years Day

MLK Day

President's Day

Memorial Day

Juneteenth

Independence Day

Labor Day

Columbus Day

Veteran's Day

Thanksgiving

Christmas

The longest gap between two federal Holidays is between Presidents Day (Floating Mid Feb) and Memorial Day (Floating Last Monday May), and the shortest gap is Christmas to New Years, which is 7 days.

Additionally, the President has the authority to declare any particular date a Federal Holiday for that one instance (This is usually used on the date of the State Funeral for a Former President OR more often in situations where a date specific holiday is set on an awkward day for a gap in the holiday (I.E. If Christmas Day is on a Tuesday, it's not uncommon for Christmas Eve to be declared a Federal Holiday)).   Additionally, if your position is a Holiday Essential employee, you are given holiday pay and are entitled to another day in the pay period to take as a Federal Holiday.

EDIT:  Additionally, if you are supposed to work on an unusual weekend schedule (I.E. you work Saturday/Sunday and are off Tues/Weds) you are entitled to a holiday off during the same pay period if you were scheduled to have off during the holiday scheduled.

Comment: All good information, but none of it answers the question.

Comment: How does this answer what happens when a holiday falls on a weekend? Also it should be noted that it is impossible for 6 of those to fall on a weekend as they fall on a set day in the work week.

Comment: Per OP "I also tried to find an authoritative list of observed holidays on a government site, but failed. All the lists I found were compiled by private web sites. I'd rather know the actual rules anyway."   Answering this issue.

Comment: I included a link in the question to a wikipedia article which lists the same 11 holidays.  How did you think I was ignorant of them?  The information I'm looking for is a way to get precise dates for when government offices will be closed for a particular holiday.

Comment: @MarkRansom The specific date depends on the specific government office because the Federal Government does have some offices that are 24/7 operations.   General rule is the Monday following the Weekend Holiday (The holidays that are floating Mondays were originally date specific but moved for the Monday Convince).  Generally it's best to call the office ahead and ask for availability.

Answer (score 1):

It's poorly worded on Wikipedia. It is using "observed" in the sense of "when the holiday actually occurs" rather than "a day off work". The holidays that you list (New Year's Day, Juneteenth, Independence Day, Veterans Day, and Christmas Day) are the ones that are defined by date. Veterans' Day always occurs on Nov. 11th and no one's going to act like Christmas happens on Dec. 26th, even if the 25th is a Sunday.

In contrast, the other holidays are defined by the "Nth Monday of the month" (or Thursday, in the case of Thanksgiving). Thus, the date changes every year, but the day of the week is fixed.

As the other answers note, government employees get the nearest weekday off, so Mon. Jan 2, 2023 was a day off this year. Last year, Fri. Dec 31, 2021 was a day off for New Year's 2022. Don't worry, they aren't missing out on any time off.

Comment: Yes, if Christmas is on a Saturday, kids don't have to wait till Monday to get presents, church services are still held on the 25th, shops normally open on a Saturday will tend to shut, etc.